# Ask user to enter username in a command window

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, powershell, command-prompt

**Hello Dears,**

how can i ask a user to enter username while executing sql script and use this value in sql script as input?

```
sqlcmd.exe -E -i script.sql
```

Comment: does your script.sql contain stored procedure to which you want to pass user input as parameter?

Comment: acutally it is a sql a job and i want ot define the job owner during installation. i found something sqlcmd -v MyVar1="i want to read input from user here" -E -i script.sql and then i will user var1 inside my script

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can set an environment variable with that value and read it with SQLCMD, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` CmdLet :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "srvName" -Database "dbName" -Username "JPB" -Password "silogix" -InputFile "C:\silogix\script.sql" | Out-File "C:\silogix\script.log"
```